# Use Webpack to package an ES6 module

Tags: node.js, webpack

I want to use Webpack for my new ES6 projects, including both full webapps and components that will be published to NPM.

For components, I want Webpack to convert my module's ES6 code into a single ES5 bundle which will then be published, *but* to not package its dependencies and instead transpile ES6 `import` statements to `require()` statements. This way, the consuming package handles packaging of the dependencies, and I won't end up with (e.g.) multiple copies of jQuery precompiled into various included components.

**How can I use Webpack to only package my module code and leave the dependencies as `require()` statements?**

Answer (score 0):

Specify the dependencies as [`externals`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals), and specify [`target`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target)`: 'node'` for the target.

Partial example:

```
{
  // CommonJS target output format
  output: { libraryTarget: "commonjs" },

  // Assumes all relative paths start with a '.'
  externals: /^[^.]/,

  target: 'node'
}
```